# Webserver process monitoring using Jmeter

Tags: profiling, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to monitor some process on webserver , like w3wp.exe and some C# written Zipping process and so on while Jmeter tests are running.
Is there a way to monitor particular process [not all] of the server using JMeter while tests are running ?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through the "Perfmon Jmeter plugin" blog mentioned below:

http://shantonusarker.blogspot.com/2013/06/perfmon-jmeter-server-monitoring-plugin.html

you will be able to monitor a particular process using "Metric parameter-EXEC" option in Perfmon Jmeter plugin

hope this will help.